# How to set a file (picture) properly into a Retrofit request body

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, multipart

I am trying to upload a picture to server with retrofit but i get the error:
 `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/image:21269: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`
After i get my picture URI i transform it to File and send it to my function which looks like this:

```
override suspend fun uploadProfilePicture(userId: Long, file: File): ApiCallResource<Int> {
        val part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
            name = "image",
            filename = file.name,
            file.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull())
        )

        val response = userService.postProfilePic(userId, part)
        return if(response.code() == 200) {
            ApiCallResource.Success(1)
        } else {
            val errorMessage = response.errorBody()!!.string()
            val jObjError = JSONObject(errorMessage)
            ApiCallResource.Error(jObjError.getString("message"))
        }
    }
```

the post emthod looks like this:

```
@Multipart
    @POST("/{userId}/postUserProfile")
    suspend fun postProfilePic(
        @Path("userId") userId: Long,
        @Part image: MultipartBody.Part
    ): Response<ResponseBody>
```

In the manifest i have these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
```

I tried opening the URI as InputStream and set the body of the image as ByteArray and it works, but I would like to know why do i keep getting the ("java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/image:21269: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory") exception.
From the URI I am getting the File like this: `val file: File = File(it[0].path)`

Comment: Use the uri. Open an input stream for the uri. Google for inputstreamrequestbody.